# Duplicate django objects with ManyToManyFields

Tags: python, django, duplicates, manytomanyfield

I use Django and I have some objects with ManyToManyFields. I'd like to duplicate these objects.
I've found 'deepcopy' which works almost perfectly.

```
>>> e = Equipement.objects.get(pk=568)
>>> ee = deepcopy(e)
>>> ee.connexion.all()
[<Connexion: COMETE - Proxyweb>]
>>> ee.id=None
>>> ee.save()
>>> ee.connexion.all()
[]
```

I don't want to loose the ManyToMany information when I save. Do you know a trick in order to do that quickly in Django ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add them using the old object:

```
ee = deepcopy(e)
ee.id=None
ee.save()
ee.connexion.add(*e.connexion.all())
```